# How to delete a row from a database using swal jquery plugin?

Tags: java, jquery

I am trying to delete a user from a database using the code above. But it isn't executing. What to do?

```
function confirmDelete(id) {
var x = swal({
    title: "Sure?",
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
    confirmButtonText: 'Delete!',
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
});
if (x == closeOnConfirm) {
    window.location.href = "/user/delete/" + id;
    swal('Deleted!', 'It was deleted.', 'success');
}
}
```